Problema con patrón de correo electrónico en html
<form action="">
    <label for="correo">Correo electrónico:</label>
    <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo" pattern="(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-](?!-){1,63}@(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9]{2,63}(?!-).[a-z]{2,}" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Probar">
</form>

He tratado de buscar un patrón en html que me permita poner guión unicamente en el medio del texto, antes y después del @ (ej: ejem-plo@domi-nio.com) pero no encuentro la manera de poder hacerlo sin que vuelva a saltar la verificación por defecto del type="email".
Ejemplos de lo que trato de que no se verifiquen como un correo válido:
-ejemplo@dominio.com
ejemplo-@dominio.com
ejemplo@-dominio.com
ejemplo@dominio-.com

Gracias de antemano por la gente que quiera ayudar.
Nota: la solución, de ser posible, que sea usando el atributo pattern y no con ayuda de un archivo Javascript.

¿has probado de usar https://regex101.com/ para jugar con ello?  Te puede ser útil si no lo conoces

Lo probé pero por ejemplo el patrón ^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}[^-@]{1}[@]{1}(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}[^-][.]{1}[a-z]{2,}$ es válido en ese simulador pero al ponerlo en el pattern no funciona

Diría yo que una primera aproximación sería asegurarse que si o si, el primer caracter sea a-zA-Z y el último sea a-zA-Z0-9.
Lo anterior se podría hacer con ambas partes del correo (antes y después del @), pero el atributo type="email" por si solo invalida los dominios, o parte de dominio, que empiezan y terminan con -, por ejemplo ejemplo@dominio-.com.
Si cambiaras el campo a text (no recomendado), tendrás que crear un regex más complejo para evitar esto.


<form action="">
    <label for="correo">Correo electrónico:</label>
    <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo" 
    pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Probar">
</form>




Aún faltaría  limitar los caracteres entre ejemplo y dominio de 1 a 63 pero igualmente gracias por tu aporte ;)
